# How to open another activity from Interface method

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-intent, start-activity

I write an application in Kotlin language on the platform Firebase. And after authentication, I need to open another activity from Interface.

While checking I get the error in this line:

```
startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, AnotherActivity::class.java))
```

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

My code:

Interface:

```
interface OnResultSuccessListener  {
    fun onResultSuccess(isSuccess: Boolean)
}
```

class an Authentication:

```
class AuthenticationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnResultSuccessListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication)
        ...
    }

    override fun onResultSuccess(isSuccess: Boolean) {          
        if (isSuccess) {
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, AnotherActivity::class.java)) /*ERROR IS HERE*/
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Helper class with CRUD methods Firebase:

```
class FirestoreCRUD {

    val db = Firebase.firestore
    var geoPoint: GeoPoint? = null

    private val authenticationActivity = AuthenticationActivity()

    val COLLECTION_USERS = "Users"
    ...
    ...
    //add new user to Firestore
    fun addNewUserToFirestore(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
            .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    // Add a new document with a generated ID
                    db.collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
                        .document(firebaseUser.uid)
                        .set(userModel)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                            /*CALL onResultSuccess IN AuthenticationActivity */                           
                            authenticationActivity.onResultSuccess(true)

                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error adding document", e)
                            authenticationActivity.onResultSuccess(false)
                        }
                }
                else authenticationActivity.onResultSuccess(false)
            })
    }
}
```

Call *onActivityResult* failed from *onResultSuccess*.

I will happy for any help!

Thanks a lop!

Comment: Your context is null

Comment: @Mustansir, I see it. But how to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know Kotlin so I can't give you a code answer but you can try returning a static context instance from your application class and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I resolved the problem. It was easy.

How said Tenfour04:

> The only way the context of an Activity can be null is if you are passing around an instance of your Activity that you instantiated yourself, which you should never do...

It is true.

Solution:

1. should send **context** to FirestoreCRUD class:

   `FirestoreUtil(this).addNewUserToFirestore(user)`
2. FirestoreCRUD class receivers straight to Interface:

   `class FirestoreUtil(var onResultSuccessListener: OnResultSuccessListener) {}`
3. And call the Interface method in AuthenticationActivity class from FirestoreCRUD class:

   `onResultSuccessListener!!.onResultSuccess(true)`

And then my activity doesn't restart and everything runs smoothly!

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The only way the context of an Activity can be null is if you are passing around an instance of your Activity that you instantiated yourself, which you should never do. Would have to see more of your code to know where you are doing that.

Comment: Ok. Can you write a little example, please?

Comment: If this appears anywhere in your code, you are doing something very wrong: `AuthenticationActivity()`. Use "Find in path" to see if you've tried to instantiate your Activity anywhere. Activities must only be instantiated by the OS. Android sets up properties like the Activity's context when it instantiates it, before you ever have access to the instance. There is nothing useful you can do with an Activity that you have instantiated yourself.

Comment: I understand you. Sorry for a stupid question, but how can I call `onResultSuccess(true)` from `FirestoreCRUD` class, if it `AuthenticationActivity().onResultSuccess(true)` is not work? Thank you!